# HTTP post em Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-services

Estou tentando acessar um serviço web que recebe no Header "Device" e no Body "Usuario e Senha", ele me retorna json neste formato:

```
{
  "IdUsuario": 2,
  "Usuario": "Fulanu",
  "Token": "1f7b87d7" 
}
```

Tentando fazer isso no angular, segue o meu código:

```
$scope.logar = function (){
  var data = ({Usuario: "usu",Senha:"sen"});
  var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;',
                'data': {Device:"1"}
            }
        }

  $http.post("URL", data,config).success(function(data, status){
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

Isso está me retornando seguinte erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Se você está fazendo uma requisição, configure na sua API o CORS,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado pessoal,

Embora não deu certo das formas que vocês sugeriram.

resolvi no meu server mesmo (MVC WebApi) com seguinte código no WebApiConfig

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins:"*", headers:"*", methods:"*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Também no envio o meu data ficou assim:

```
 var data = "Usuario=fulanu&Senha=senha";
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando acessar um serviço de um arquivo local. Isso não é possível pela política de mesma origem, a menos que você habilite o acesso do lado do servidor enviando `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` nos `headers`.

> Em computação, a política de mesma origem é um conceito importante no modelo de segurança de aplicações web. Esta política permite que scripts sejam executados em páginas que se originam do mesmo site - uma combinação de esquema, nome de hospedeiro e número de porta - para acessar o DOM um do outro sem restrições específicas, mas impede acesso a DOM em sites diferentes.[1] Esta política também se aplica a XMLHttpRequests a menos que o servidor forneça um cabeçalho Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS). Notavelmente WebSockets não estão sujeitos a política de mesma origem.

Porém para fins de desenvolvimento no chrome você pode iniciar com os seguintes parâmetros:

```
--allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

No Windows ficará semelhante ao seguinte:

```
C:\Users\SEU USUARIO\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

**Referência:** [CORS, Cordova, AngularJs $http and file:// confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914071/cors-cordova-angularjs-http-and-file-confusion)

Comment: Não é possível? Tem certeza? De nenhuma forma?

Comment: Você pode iniciar o Chrome com "--allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security"

Comment: Só isso????????

Comment: Ou configurar o servidor pra aceitar qualquer origem. Seu serviço é em que?

Comment: Não é meu serviço, eu só vim te dizer que a resposta tá incompleta. Pra mim sua resposta tá muito ruim, mas eu não vou negativar. Só tenta arrumar ela.

Comment: tem alguma forma de resolver isso do lado cliente? porque este meu serviço está sendo consumido por outros sistemas, e funcionam

Answer (score 1):

Recentemente passei pelo mesmo problema enquanto tentava obter dados de uma API externa que bloqueava minhas requisições com o mesmo erro que o seu. O que eu fiz para resolver o problema foi criar uma configuração para todos os serviços $http através de um `interceptor` (que é um serviço que "intercepta" toda requisição e aplica a configuração antes de ser executada). Veja:

```
angular
.module('seuModulo')
.config('InterceptorConfig', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
})
```

Veja se resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Onde é que eu coloco isso?
porque coloquei aqui angular.module("meu mod",[]);
angular.module("meu mod").config('InterceptorConfig', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
}); e está dando erro.

Comment: @MidanaSana E uma nova configuração, depende da sua estrutura, mas no meu caso, é um novo arquivo.

Comment: amigo, gostaria de testar essa sua sugestão, mas também não entendi onde colocar ....